# Spring Boot on WildFly (or Undertow): Servlet Filter's orders are reversed

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly, undertow

I deployed my `Spring Boot Web application on WildFly 8.1`, but now I have some trouble.

When application was deployed, `FilterRegistrationBeans` register Servlet Filters. I know `FilterRegistrationBean`s are oredered by `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator`, and those filters are registerd by that order. But when I access my application,  Undertow calls filters by reversed order.

For example, if Spring Boot register filters like that:

> - errorPageFilter
> - metricFilter (from Spring Boot actuator)
> - characterEncodingFilter
> - hiddenHttpMethodFilter
> - springSecurityFilterChain (from Spring Security)

Undertow call those filters like that:

> - springSecurityFilterChain
> - hiddenHttpMethodFilter
> - characterEncodingFilter
> - metricFilter
> - errorPageFilter

How can I specify those filters order correctly? Some filter's order (like `org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter`) was hard-coded in source, I can't specify that.

Comment: Have you tried this on Tomcat or any other Java EE app server ? Wondering if this is a Boot problem, or WildFly ?

Comment: I'm trying on WildFly and Embedded Tomcat. On Tomcat the filters order is collect (it's I expected), but on WildFly the order is that described above.

Comment: Checking within the team and will get back to you.

Comment: And now this has been answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an Undertow bug that occurs when matchAfter is false in FilterRegistrationImpl#addMappingForUrlPatterns, instead of inserting the filter before all declared filters it inserts it before all filters.